# PostgreSQL issue with update JSON Array

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

I have column of type `JSON[]` and I want to update this column by using the concat `||` operator.

Initial Data is `'[{"name":"abcd","type":"pqrs"}]'`

When i try to concat this with `'[{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}]'`

The result which is expected is

`'[{"name":"abcd","type":"pqrs"},{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}]'`

but instead it becomes `'[{"name":"abcd","type":"pqrs"},[{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}]]'`

The Stored Procedure which is used is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_attendance(data json)
RETURNS character varying
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
       UPDATE public.amdata 
       SET attendance_data = attendance_data || data,
       WHERE something = something;
   RETURN 0;
 END;
 $$;
```

Comment: you add element to array of json values - the result as expected?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I am trying to concatenate two JSON array elements but instead it is getting inserted.

Comment: but this is the result of concatenating several jsons! your expected result is not concat of json+json[] it is merging of json[1] and json - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

here to mock up what you have:

```
t=# create table so14 (j json[]);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so14 select '{}';
INSERT 0 1
t=# update so14 set j[1] = '{"name":"abcd","type":"pqrs"}';
UPDATE 1
t=# with a as (
select j[1],(j||'[{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}]'::json) ct from so14
)
select array_to_json(ct),ct[1],ct[2] from a;

t=# select array_to_json(j||'{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}'::json) ct from so14;
                              ct
---------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"name":"abcd","type":"pqrs"},{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}]
(1 row)

Time: 0.295 ms
```

so your concat behaves as expected: it appends `'[{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}]]'::json` to array

If you want to build json with array of jsons (as in your question expected part) you have to build it like

```
t=# select array_to_json(j||'{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}'::json) ct from so14;
                          ct
---------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"name":"abcd","type":"pqrs"},{"name":"dbca","type":"asdd"}]
(1 row)

Time: 0.295 ms
```

notice I removed **[** **]** brackets in json you concat...

also notice I use `array_to_json` just for pretty display of `json[]` value